# Linux swap position on hdd

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance, swap, performance-tuning

As far as I know hard drives are faster at the beginning of the disk. If this is true, why does Ubuntu put the swap partition to the back of the disk by default?

Comment: I think this should be asked in askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

As memory prices have dropped, average memory in computers has increased. The dependence on swap has decreased.

Comment: this still doesn't justify putting the swap partition in the end.